# Configuration Error: <compilation debug=“true” targetFramework=“4.0”> Plesk?

Tags: asp.net, plesk

I've installed Plesk on windows 2008 server and when i moved the website content "`ASP`" to the new account created by Plesk i got this Error

[image]

```
Line 56: 
Line 57:     <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
Line 58:     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
Line 59:       <assemblies>
Line 60:         <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions,  Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

i am not ASP developer , the website was running good on server IP , but after i installed `Plesk` and copy the website content to the Plesk account i got this

any advice ? or how i can hair ASP developer to assist me how to change website configurations to `Plesk` if necessary ?

[image]

Comment: Can you manually change the `Web.Config`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found the solution , Plesk depends on 2.0 version of .Net framework all i have to do to change Plesk Pool to 4.0 version

[image]